# id cannot be zero error while inserting new entity

Tags: android, google-app-engine, jpa

I am trying to insert a new entity in app engine datastore using JPA. I am getting the error below. Can someone please suggest what could be wrong.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id cannot be zero
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.createKey(KeyFactory.java:52)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.createKey(KeyFactory.java:47)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.createKey(KeyFactory.java:35)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.intOrLongToInternalKey(EntityUtils.java:381)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.idToInternalKey(EntityUtils.java:220)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.idToInternalKey(EntityUtils.java:208)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreIdentityKeyTranslator.getKey(DatastoreIdentityKeyTranslator.java:32)
```

Here is my entity class

```
   //imports
   @Entity
   public class QuizTable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String quizName;
private String quizContent;

public QuizTable(){}

public Long getId() {return id;}
public String getQuizName() {return quizName;}
public String getQuizContent() {return quizContent;}

public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id;}
public void setQuizName(String quizName) {this.quizName=quizName;}
public void setQuizContent(String quizContent) {this.quizContent=quizContent;}

 }
```

Comment: your id is 0, but it cannot.

Answer (score 0):

The id is generated automatically (cause you wanted to), it shouldn't have a setter method. remove the automatic generation and set it manually if you prefer.

Comment: commented the setId() method in entity. Still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I work with JPA and it works fine. im not sure what your problem but you can try this:

1. How if you change your generation type to `GenerationType.IDENTITY`?
2. How if you use native `long` instead of `Long`?

Comment: native long would be even worse - as it defaults to 0.